# Partitioning in Spark while writing to delta

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a dataframe to a delta table using the following code:

```py
(df
 .write
 .format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .partitionBy("date")
 .saveAsTable("table"))
```

I have 32 distinct dates in the format `yyyy-mm`, and I am expecting to have 32 partitions, but if I run `print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())`, I get only 15.  What am I missing?

Comment: `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy` will define how your data will be outputted regardless how many partitions it already has. If you want shuffle your data and move them between 32 partitions you must execute `df = df.repartition('date')`

Comment: Should I do it before the write statement?  It returns a default of 200.

Comment: Yes, but it also can be written after the last action that executes a shuffle, like GroupBy or Join operations.

Comment: Is there a way to point me to a good example that would explain your statement?